# List range error on getting email from Firestore..... Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a simple chat app, I have stored the user email and user name in firebase so now I want to get the user email for searching the user in the search bar through his email id.
This is my code :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:light_chat/layout/const_size.dart';
import 'package:light_chat/layout/repeateCode.dart';
import 'sign_in.dart';
import 'functions.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 late final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 bool isLoading = false;
 late Map<String, dynamic> userMap;
 TextEditingController _serachBarController = TextEditingController();
 void onSearch()async{

 FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  setState(() {
 isLoading = true;
  });
  await _firestore.collection('users').where('email', isEqualTo: _serachBarController.text)
  .get().then((value){
    setState(() {
```

Error line # userMap

```
      userMap = value.docs[0].data();
      print(userMap);
      isLoading = false;
    });

   });
  }
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home'),
   backgroundColor: Colors.blue,),
    body: isLoading ?
   Center(child:
    Container(
      height: size.height / 20,
      width:  size.width / 20,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),)
      :Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
        RepeateTextFieldCode(controller: _serachBarController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            lableText: 'Search'),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => onSearch(),
          child: Text('Search',style: buttonText,),
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
       ),
       ),
      ],
     ),
     );
     }
    }
```

Error is :

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36).
```

My firestore DB is not empty, I have added some users for getting emails. so flutter is throwing exceptions when I write the user email id on the search bar and click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, you are getting empty list but calling 1st item(index 0). Try to check length of list and then use index value

```dart
if(value.docs.length>0){
     userMap = value.docs[0].data();
  }
```

Comment: Bro this method is not working.

Comment: what do you get now

Comment: thanks, bro for your attention, the error was my own mistake i was not adding user email in Firebase firestore db, so when i added in it the issue had solved.